# Generate 20 random number in a range with enthropy

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic, probability

I'm looking for solution to my problem. Say I have a number X, now  I want to generate 20 random numbers whose sum would equal to X, but I want those random numbers to have enthropy in them. So for example, if X = 50, the algorithm should generate

- 3
- 11
- 0
- 6
- 19
- 7

etc. The sum of given numbres should equal to 50.
Is there any simple way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "have entropy".  Are you using that phrase as another way of saying you want the values to be random?

Comment: Yes, I want the values to be random, but I want the values to be different from each others. So instead of generating for example five 10s, I want it to generate 5 different numbers.

Comment: Are any duplicates allowed?

Comment: @pjs No, duplicates are not allowed. Maybe one duplicate in ~10 run or so would be fine, but in general no :)

Comment: If you want 20 distinct numbers that add up to 50, it's not going to happen.  Sum(i) for i=1..20 is 210, substantially bigger than 50.  You're going to have to have some duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way:
Generate random number between 1 and X : say R1;
subtract R1 from X, now generate a random number between 1 and (X - R1) : say R2. Repeat the process until all Ri add to X : i.e. (X-Rn) is zero. Note: each consecutive number Ri will be smaller then the first. If you want the final sequence to look more random, simply permute the resulting Ri numbers. I.e. if you generate for X=50, an array like: 22,11,9,5,2,1 - permute it to get something like 9,22,2,11,1,5. You can also put a limit to how large any random number can be.

Comment: I'll give it a try and post the result. Thx :)

Comment: This could take any number of steps, could it not? If not, then the 20th number would have be R20 so it lacks true randomness (since it's defined by it's predecessors).

Comment: 22, 11 1 8 3 2 5 3 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. All tests are similar to this. Higher numbers always comes first with this method. Is there any way to distribute higher numbers a bit more randomly?

Comment: @Aidan Gomez, yes any number of steps (random), I don't think the user was asking for a set number of steps, but if so, can easily be modified to produce a set number of steps.

Comment: @NickoPo damn you r good at this :)) I'll need time to analyze everything :)))

Answer (score 0):

One fairly straightforward way to get k random values that sum to N is to create an array of size k+1, add values 0 and N, and fill the rest of the array with k-1 randomly generated values between 1 and N-1.  Then sort the array and take the differences between successive pairs.

Here's an implementation in Ruby:

```
def sum_k_values_to_n(k = 20, n = 50)
  a = Array.new(k + 1) { 1 + rand(n - 1) }
  a[0] = 0
  a[-1] = n
  a.sort!
  (1..(a.length - 1)).collect { |i| a[i] - a[i-1] }
end

p sum_k_values_to_n(3, 10) # produces, e.g., [2, 3, 5]    
p sum_k_values_to_n  # produces, e.g., [5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 0, 4, 4, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5, 7, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```